# Trigger.io launchimage module 'Hide Manually' is not working

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I want to control when launch image is hidden on ios device. I have set up 'hide manually' to true, but nothing changed. Launch image fades out on its own shortly after the launch. I use all the latest versions of the plugin (2.6) and the platform (2.2.3). It works if I downgrade launch image module to 2.4. Am I missing something? How can I debug this?

Cheers

Comment: Same issue here too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in [version 2.7](https://trigger.io/modules/launchimage/current/versions/).

Comment: yep :], fixed some other issues too. Like image disappearing before page fully loaded.